# Make sidebar sticky at a specific point of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar with links that are changing when I'm scrolling a long content. The problem is that the change is happening too early when the chapter title is barely at the bottom of the page.

How can I write `if(fromTop >= 100)` differently, to get sticky when it reaches the `row startContent`?

Thanks for any suggestions!

```js
// Sticky sidebar scroll
        let stickyLinks = document.getElementById("scrollspy");
        let mobNavStick = document.getElementById("navTop");
        let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#scrollspy ul li a");
    let footer = document.querySelector('footer');

        window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
            let fromTop = window.scrollY;
      //start from a spe
            if(fromTop >= 100){
                stickyLinks.classList.add("sticky");
            }
            else {
                stickyLinks.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
      // add link gray background
      mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
                let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

                if (section.offsetTop <= fromTop && section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop) {
                    link.classList.add("current");
                } else {
                    link.classList.remove("current");
                }
            });
    });
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 18px;
}
p {
font-size: 12px;
}
container {
width: 75%;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}
#scrollspy ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#scrollspy ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: block;
}
#scrollspy ul li:first-child {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1rem;
}
#scrollspy ul li a.current {
    background: #eee;
  }
  
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<!--some header on top-->
<div class="row startContent">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- content and sidebar -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="scrollspy">
        <ul>
            <li>Contents</li>
            <li><a href="#chapter1">Link 1</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter2">Link 2</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter3">Link 3</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter4">Link 4</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter5">Link 5</a><li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="chapter1">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 1<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter2">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 2<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter3">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 3<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter4">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 4<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter5">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 5<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an identifier to the container of the chapters, so the sidebar gets sticky only when the top of such container reaches the top of the window. Is this what you intended?

```js
// Sticky sidebar scroll
let stickyLinks = document.getElementById("scrollspy");
let mobNavStick = document.getElementById("navTop");
let mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#scrollspy ul li a");
let footer = document.querySelector('footer');

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  //start from a spe
  if(fromTop > mainContent.offsetTop){
    stickyLinks.classList.add("sticky");
  }
  else {
    stickyLinks.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
  // add link gray background
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

    if (section.offsetTop <= fromTop && section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 18px;
}
p {
font-size: 12px;
}
container {
width: 75%;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}
#scrollspy ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#scrollspy ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: block;
}
#scrollspy ul li:first-child {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1rem;
}
#scrollspy ul li a.current {
    background: #eee;
  }
  
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<!--some header on top-->
<div class="row startContent">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- content and sidebar -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="scrollspy">
        <ul>
            <li>Contents</li>
            <li><a href="#chapter1">Link 1</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter2">Link 2</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter3">Link 3</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter4">Link 4</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter5">Link 5</a><li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent" class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="chapter1">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 1<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter2">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 2<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter3">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 3<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter4">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 4<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter5">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 5<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to do it without js only with pure css position sticky property:

```css
h2 {
font-size: 18px;
}
p {
font-size: 12px;
}
container {
width: 75%;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}
#scrollspy ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#scrollspy ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: block;
}
#scrollspy ul li:first-child {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1rem;
}
#scrollspy ul li a.current {
    background: #eee;
  }
  
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sticky-nav {
  margin-bottom: -250px;
  position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<!--some header on top-->
<div class="row startContent">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4 style="height: 200px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="sticky-nav">
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="scrollspy">
        <ul>
            <li>Contents</li>
            <li><a href="#chapter1">Link 1</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter2">Link 2</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter3">Link 3</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter4">Link 4</a><li>
            <li><a href="#chapter5">Link 5</a><li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- content and sidebar -->
<div class="row offset-3">
    
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="chapter1">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 1<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter2">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 2<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter3">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 3<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter4">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 4<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
        <div id="chapter5">
            <h2>Title of Chapter 5<h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies, lacus eu viverra euismod, arcu dolor condimentum augue, vel congue est ante sit amet purus. Quisque non nunc ut urna gravida porta. Duis sodales vitae tortor in feugiat. Praesent tellus ante, pharetra sed mauris at, eleifend semper nisl. Donec condimentum purus eget viverra euismod. Ut felis ipsum, sagittis sodales faucibus suscipit, tempus a ante. Integer ac dignissim libero. In tincidunt purus at urna consectetur eleifend. Nullam hendrerit nulla et enim auctor rhoncus. Pellentesque interdum augue nec augue pulvinar fermentum. Phasellus imperdiet elit id arcu vehicula, ac commodo mauris hendrerit.</p>
        </div> <!--End of chapter 0-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```